# Old answers converted to comments shouldn't show up as new messages in the global inbox

Tags: feature-request, global-inbox, convert-to-comment

A comment from 2009 has just shown up at the top of my inbox.  Initially it showed as one minute old, a few minutes later it's showing 4 minutes ago, so the time error appears to be dynamic not static.

According to @Mat (presumably via 10k tools)

> That comment was initially an answer (posted on Dec 9 '09 at 22:03).
>
> It was converted to a comment a few minutes ago (11:07Z) by a moderator (most likely following a flag and/or review actions), which explains the notification.

Since I already received notice of this information when it was first posted 5 years ago, adding it to my Inbox again is just noise.  Displaying a notice for it doesn't add any value and shouldn't occur.

[image]

Comment: I think it is good to get indication such thing happened. The only missing thing is some indication the comment was previously an answer, which makes it confusing indeed.

Comment: @ShadowWizard for a recent question maybe.  For something that's years old, not so much...