# Received a new comment reply notification about a comment reply posted 10 months ago

Tags: bug, global-inbox, comment-replies

This morning, I received a notification of a new reply to a comment I made.

But that reply was made 10 months ago, yet the inbox says it was made 5 hours ago.

[image: thumbnail of screenshot showing bug]

The question in question is [this one](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/55343/rooted-device-with-superuser-but-terminal-emulator-denied-permission).  I'm not sure whether or not I received a notification when the reply was actually posted.

Comment: Most likely same as [this one](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/238249/old-answers-converted-to-comments-shouldnt-show-up-as-new-messages-in-the-globa), old answer that turned into a comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The comment was converted from an answer about 5 hours ago by a moderator.

As a comment, it is indeed new.

Comment: I guess the notification is new? Two reports in a row after years without any such report.

Comment: @ShadowWizard - not sure. Could be a change elsewhere.

Comment: @ShadowWizard this is my bug - will look at it today.